# Adblock plus - hide part of css style or change class name?

Tags: html, css, adblock

Adblock hides the adverts on http://www.outlook.com but leaves an empty sidebar which i want to remove
There are 2 methods i found to remove the sidebar manually but i want to do it with adblock plus

Method 1:
the sidebar div is set as:

```
<div id="contentRight" class="ContentRight WithSkyscraper">
```

by removing WithSkyscraper from the class the sidebar is hidden.

Method 2:
The other way of doing it is in the css file there is a class:

```
.App.Unmanaged .ContentRight.WithSkyscraper #ManagedContentWrapper
{
padding-right:160px;
}
```

by deleting padding-right or changing 160px to 0px the sidebar also hides

is it possible to do one of these 2 methods with adblock plus? Or is there another addon that could be used

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I installed the addon Stylish on to firefox and created my own style to change the width to 0px

```
.App.Unmanaged .ContentRight.WithSkyscraper #ManagedContentWrapper 
{
padding-right: 0px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try and install an other plugin which allows you to apply custom CSS code to the websites, or edit the one they got.
For example, if you use Chrome, [Stylebot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha) seems like a viable option for you.
As far as I know plugins like this should work with Adblock, so you just have to edit the CSS and use your websites the way you want to.